# Nginx and php-fpm application but nginx not reading correct socket

Tags: php, sockets, nginx

I have installed nginx and php-fpm: dnf module -y install nginx php:7.3/common

Create the folder for socker file: mkdir /var/run/php-fpm

Edit the php-fpm conf file, to modify contents below: vi /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

user = nginx

group = nginx

listen = /run/php-fpm/default.sock

Start php-fpm service: systemctl start php-fpm

Check the file is created: ls /var/run/php-fpm : return default.sock

Change ownership for nginx to access folder: chown -R root:nginx /var/lib/php

Edit nginx conf file: vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf'''

```
server {
    listen       8093;
    listen       [::]:8093;
    server_name  _;
    root         /var/www/html;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Start nginx : systemctl start nginx

Both are in running with systemctl status

But if i do a curl to the nginx, it could not read the php index file.

checking the nginx logs with: cat /var/log/nginx/error.log

I get the following error:
2023/11/16 02:39:50 [crit] 1658#0: *1 connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.238.2, server: _, request: “GET /index.php HTTP/1.1”, upstream: “fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:”, host: “stapp01:8093”
2023/11/16 02:39:50 [error] 1658#0: *1 open() “/var/www/html/50x.html” failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.16.238.2, server: _, request: “GET /index.php HTTP/1.1”, upstream: “fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock”, host: “stapp01:8093”

I have configure nginx to read from default.sock, why nginx keep looking for www.sock?

Please advise, thanks.

23Nov2023(solved)
from https://www.tecmint.com/connect-nginx-to-php-fpm/

vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf : add the below block

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm.conf

```
# PHP-FPM FastCGI server
# network or unix domain socket configuration

upstream php-fpm {
    server unix:/run/php-fpm/default.sock;
}
```

And it works. Thanks Aaron Kili.